# Animate NSButton resizing when modifying imagePosition property

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-animation, autolayout, nsbutton

I have an NSButton subclass in an autolayout environment. The subclass implements mouseEntered: and mouseExited: methods, which should change the positioning of the button's image. On mouseEntered: it is changed to NSImageLeft (showing the title) and on mouseExited: it is changed to NSImageOnly (not showing the title).

Autolayout takes care of the resizing of the NSButton subclass in my view hierarchy, but it does not look smooth as it is not using CoreAnimation for resizing the button width according to whether the title is to be shown or not. How can I let the resizing happen with an animation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using the following methods:

```
- (void)mouseEntered:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    NSSize titleStringSize = [self.title sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[NSFont     boldSystemFontOfSize:11.0]}];
    self.widthConstraint.animator.constant = titleStringSize.width+self.originalWidth+5.0;
}

- (void)mouseExited:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    self.widthConstraint.animator.constant = self.originalWidth;
}
```

`originalWidth` and `widthConstraint` are properties of my NSButton subclass that are defined during `awakeFromNib`.

Answer (score 0):

Open an animation group, enable implicit animations, change the button image position, and then force layout:

```
[NSAnimationContext runAnimationGroup:^(NSAnimationContext *context){
    context.allowsImplicitAnimation = YES;
    button.imagePosition = NSImageOnly;
    [button.window layoutIfNeeded];
} completionHandler:nil];
```

Comment: If I add that piece of code to both methods (mouseEntered: and mouseExited:), it still does not animate, but simply changes the width of the button immediately.

Comment: Try `button.animator.imagePosition = NSImageOnly;`.

Comment: I tried that as well, but there is still no animation. The width is changed immediately.

Comment: I just tested my original code using Xcode 5.1 and OS X 10.9.4. It works. The button's frame animates between the two sizes. (The interior of the button immediately changes whether it draws with the title or not, which causes the image to jump a bit.) Did you perhaps surround the code in another animation group whose duration was set to 0? What happens if you explicitly set `context.duration = 0.25` at the top of the block?

Comment: It might depend on the rest of the auto layout configuration. I added my own solution to the problem as an alternative answer. In my approach I modified the constraint directly.